# Where does tracker-preferences store the configuration data?

Tags: configuration, tracker

I am using tracker and I am using tracker-preferences to configure which directories it should index etc. However I see strange behaviour so I would like to look at the actual configuration file or settings tracker is using.

I could not find any hint as to where to look though: there seems to be nothing in the gconf registry, nor any config file in ~/.conf or ~/.gconf.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found it, it is shown in the dconf (not gconf) tool under key org.freedesktop.tracker...

Some time I will have to find out what the difference between dconf and gconf is and why there are so many different ways how programs store configuration under Linux.

Comment: Amen. It's horrendous and the locations and indices vary from week to week it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/Configuration you can have it store configuration in a file:

> 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME': Default is $HOME/.config/. Tracker stores
>   configuration files in here under a 'tracker' subdirectory, but ONLY
>   if the 'TRACKER_USE_CONFIG_FILES' environment variable is defined.